# How to change position of Ves Brand carousel in home page Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, cms-block, magento2.2.3

I have Magento 2.2.3 and module Ves Brand.

When I add carousel with brands it appear under menu in top part of main destination. There is no settings to change it and is difficult to find reference name of block.

I wonder how to change position of this carousel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this that I want to share.
My problem was with finding proper name of block. Solution for example to move carousel to the bottom of main container just before footer is to edit in custom theme (mine theme is using Blank theme like a base)

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
I add in the end - before body tag end.

```
<move element="brand_list" destination="main" after="-"/>
```